# Moya/Alamofire - URL encoded params with same keys

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) Swift framework for networking layer which is constructed on top of [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

Currently, I'm trying to send request with URL encoded parameters that have same keys.

i.e. `http://some-site/request?param=v1&param=v2&param=v3`

I've already tried to group these params into Set or NSSet or Array like this but nothing helps to achieve desired result.

`["param": ["v1", "v2", "v3"]];`

`["param": Set(arrayLiteral: "v1", "v2", "v3")]`

Any help would be appreciated either with Moya or with Alamofire itself.

**Edit:** Here is some sample code to give basic idea:

Api Router setup

```
import Moya

// MARK:- Enum Declaration

enum ApiRouter {
    case XAuth(login: String, password: String)
    case SomeRequest(params: [String])
}

// MARK:- Moya Path

extension ApiRouter: MoyaPath {
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .XAuth:
            return "/authorization"
        case .SomeRequest:
            return "/some-request"
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- Moya Target

extension ApiRouter: MoyaTarget {
    private var base: String {
        return "http://some-site"
    }
    var baseURL: NSURL {
        return NSURL(string: base)!
    }

    var parameters: [String: AnyObject] {
        switch self {
        case .XAuth(let login, let password):
            return [
                "email": login,
                "password": password
            ]
        case .SomeRequest(let params):
            return [
                "params": params
            ]
    }

    var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .XAuth:
            return .POST
        case .SomeRequest,
            return .GET
        }
    }

    var sampleData: NSData {
        switch self {
        case .XAuth:
            return "{}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        case .ServiceRequests:
            return "{}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }
    }
}
```

Api Provider setup

```
    let endpointsClosure = { (target: ApiRouter) -> Endpoint<ApiRouter> in
    let endpoint = Endpoint<ApiRouter>(
        URL: target.baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(target.path).absoluteString!,
        sampleResponse: EndpointSampleResponse.Success(200, { target.sampleData }),
        method: target.method,
        parameters: target.parameters,
        parameterEncoding: parameterEncoding(target)
    )
    switch target {
    case .XAuth:
        return endpoint
    default:
        let token = "some-token"
        return endpoint.endpointByAddingHTTPHeaderFields(["Authorization": "Bearer: \(token)"])
    }
}

func parameterEncoding(target: ApiRouter) -> Moya.ParameterEncoding {
    switch target {
    case .XAuth:
        return .JSON
    case .SomeRequest:
        return .URL
    }
}

let apiProvider = MoyaProvider(endpointsClosure: endpointsClosure)

apiProvider.request(ApiRouter.SomeRequest(params: ["v1", "v2", "v3"], completion: { (data, statusCode, response, error) in
    /* ... */
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify, your API is "GET" or "POST"?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon it's GET request

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: And can you please show the api which you are using to test

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I've updated my question with just some sample code, which gives the idea of what I'm doing (trying to do), and the API I'm working with is internal and can't be shown here, thanks

Comment: Are you getting any results in completion handler ? or print the error if you are receiving

Comment: @SohilR.Memon errors may vary from one API to another, but it's not really the deal.

What I'm asking is if I can somehow send request with url parameters that have same keys in the next way: `http://some-site/request?param=v1&param=v2&param=v3`. 

Because Dictionary doesn't let you have same multiple keys, and if i group values into array `[params: ["v1", "v2", "v3"]]`, then i send the next request `http://some-site/request?param[]=v1&param[]=v2&param[]=v3` which is not exactly what API is expecting to receive

Comment: If you are using .GET method then you don't need to pass the dictionary. Only for .POST Method you need to pass the parameters

Comment: @SohilR.Memon then how would you send URL encoded parameters for GET request?

Comment: If you need to encode then you have to compulsory go for .POST method

Comment: @SohilR.Memon encode what?!
Look, what i need to do, is to send GET request with URL parameters that have same keys using Moya framework. Isolate your thoughts from any networking and servers, think of this in terms of strings. In the end I need to get this URL string `http://some-site/request?param=v1&param=v2&param=v3`. It has nothing to do with POST and other stuff, just plain GET request with same param keys using Moya or Alamofire framework. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found a solution which is actually pretty simple and obvious.
Reading [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#parameter-encoding)'s documentation I found this:

> Since there is no published specification for how to encode collection types, Alamofire follows the convention of appending [] to the key for array values (foo[]=1&foo[]=2), and appending the key surrounded by square brackets for nested dictionary values (foo[bar]=baz).

So, for this cases there's **Custom** **ParameterEncoding** option which takes closure where you can actually specify your own implementation of how you want parameters to be formed.

[Here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/570)'s the same question with the same answer.

Comment: When would it be a good idea to not use Moya? Are there alternatives of to using Moya?

Comment: there are plenty libs, you name :)
you can use Alamofire or NSURLSession and create your own wrapper, there's something very similar to Moya and it's Swish from Thoughtbot. Actually networking layer is usually the same, so you can take a look at how it works here and create your own :)

Comment: @Voronv I took a look. And something that Moya or other networking abstraction layer is lacking is OAuth/JWT approach of request for refreshing/updating expired auth token prior to firing the next request. For example, if auth token is expired, the token should be updated on the client side before the next moya request... Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: @user805981it's not an issue at all, here's what Moya suggests in this case https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md#oauth

Personally I do it the same way, I put all needed modifications inside request callback which is passed into moya provider.

In my opinion network layer library shouldn't handle all this stuff for you, or it'll turn into overwhelmed and heavy RestKit-like thing.

Here's small library for OAuth handling https://github.com/trivago/Heimdallr.swift

Combine them and have a nice day :)

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example you have provided in the question but I keep getting `Cannot convert value of type 'EndpointSampleResponse' to expected argument type 'SampleResponseClosure' (aka '() -> EndpointSampleResponse')` GIST: https://gist.github.com/rlam3/5392927b462e3986fff58c15eb9f704f

Comment: @user805981 here you need a function to defer response, not a raw value

`
sampleResponseClosure: { EndpointSampleResponse.NetworkResponse(200, NSData()) }
`
but next time, it's better to create a new question, so other people could fine answer if they have same problem

Answer (score 4):

Moya is a good idea, but I actually feel that with some thinking, we can construct a network abstraction layer using Swift without much code.

Our goal is :

- Flexibility, to be able to edit or add new endpoints efficiently
- Readability, to have a good idea of how our API work at a glance
- Code safety, with typed parameters to allow all the pre-compilation goodness (completion, validation) we expect from Xcode.
- Easy debugging, meaning being able to insert logs before and after web requests

Here is what I ended up with on a [dummy project](https://github.com/kirualex/ColourLoveSwift) :

```
public class API {

public static let baseURL: String = "http://colourlovers.com/api"

public enum Endpoints {

    case Colors(String)
    case Palettes(String)
    case Patterns(String)

    public var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {
        case .Colors,
             .Palettes,
             .Patterns:
            return Alamofire.Method.GET
        }
    }

    public var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .Colors:
            return baseURL+"/colors"
        case .Palettes:
            return baseURL+"/palettes"
        case .Patterns:
            return baseURL+"/patterns"
        }
    }

    public var parameters: [String : AnyObject] {
        var parameters = ["format":"json"]
        switch self {
        case .Colors(let keywords):
            parameters["keywords"] = keywords
            break
        case .Palettes(let keywords):
            parameters["keywords"] = keywords
            break
        case .Patterns(let keywords):
            parameters["keywords"] = keywords
            break
        }
        return parameters
    }
}

public static func request(
    endpoint: API.Endpoints,
    completionHandler: Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void)
    -> Request {

        let request =  Manager.sharedInstance.request(
            endpoint.method,
            endpoint.path,
            parameters: endpoint.parameters,
            encoding: .URL,
            headers: nil
            ).responseJSON { response in

                if (response.result.error) != nil {
                    DDLogError("\n<----\n" + response.result.error!.description)
                    completionHandler(response)
                } else {
                    DDLogInfo("\n<----\n" + response.response!.description)
                    completionHandler(response)
                }
        }
        DDLogInfo("\n---->\n" + request.description)
        return request
    }
}
```

Comment: So you guys didn't use Moya?

Comment: I like this idea. In current project I worked, the network layer is useful. The App should not touch `Alamofire` directly. An extra network layer gains more flexibility, but adds more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create the String using format and pass it as a Request URL:

http://some-site/request?param=v1&param=v2&param=v3

```
String url: String = String(format: "http://some-site/request?param=%@&param=%@&param=%@", v1, v2, v3)
```

Hope this helps!