# Alamofire Passing Parameter With Common Keys and Multiple Values?

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I need to do this in my project:

I can do this easily if I manually append strings to my URL in Alamofire, but I don't want that. I want the parameters as **Parameter** object.

**multiple values in one common key for parameter**

[image]

What I've been doing:

```
public func findCreate(tags: [String], withBlock completion: @escaping FindCreateServiceCallBack) {
    
    /* http://baseurlsample.com/v1/categories/create_multiple?category_name[]=fff&category_name[]=sss */
    
    let findCreateEndpoint = CoreService.Endpoint.FindMultipleCategories
    
    let parameters: Parameters = ["category_name[]" : tags]
    
    Alamofire.request(
        findCreateEndpoint,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString),
        headers: nil
        ).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
    }
//....
}
```

The current result if I run this is okay but the values sent to the server has [" "]. For example:

```
["chocolate"]
```

Again, the questions are, in which part of my whole code I'm wrong? How can I send parameters like the above that have one common key and multiple values?

I also have tried adding **encoding** option to the **Alamofire.request()** If I add `encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted` or `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` I get **status code 500**.

Some links that have the same question but no exact answers, I always see posts that have answers like using a custom encoding and that's it.

- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/570
- [Moya/Alamofire - URL encoded params with same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910683/moya-alamofire-url-encoded-params-with-same-keys)

Additional info:

This works, but I need to send multiple String:

```
let parameters: [String : Any] = ["category_name[]" : tags.first!]
```

And this works as well:

```
Alamofire.request("http://baseurlsample.com/v1/categories/create_multiple?category_name[]=fff&category_name[]=sss", method: .post).responseJSON { (data) in
    print(data)
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a custom encoding for this format.

You can send parameters encoded like this:

```
category_name[]=rock&category_name[]=paper
```

By using `URLEncoding` (which you're already doing) and including the multiple values that should have the same key in an array:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["category_name": ["rock", "paper"]]
```

It'll add the `[]` after `category_name` for you, so don't include it when you declare the `parameters`.

Comment: Omg.. you saved my day. This answer was exactly what I was looking for. Just removing [] in parameters resolved my problem!